# Visual Studio 2008 Debugging large c file

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-2008, large-files

I am debugging a very large c file . It is approx 70000+ lines of code. The debugger is not functioning properly, However the code is compiled correctly. Is there any flag or something which needs to be set to debug this file.

Edit:

I have changed the location of the function from bottom of file to top it is now debugging the function as expected. Don't know the reason

Comment: define: "is not functioning properly"

Comment: when I step into a function the execution continues from any junk line (in the same file). I guess the source code lines move out of synch, However the result produced by the function is as expected but cannot be witnessed through debugger. I have recompiled the code because I thought the pdb file may be out of sync

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there's a 65536 line limit somewhere. E.g. if source code positions are represented in 32 bits as 16:16 line:column pairs.

Comment: @MSalters not really surprising, but still: oh my god!

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: Why? C dates back to ca. 1980, when 64K bytes was a large system. Bytes, not lines. Plenty of CPU's back then did not even _have_ 32 bits registers. A Z80 didn't even have a 16 bit accumulator. At which point should the compiler vendor have changed that to 32 bits line numbers? Correct answer: when **generated** code exceeded 64K lines - which explains why the problem now occurs in the debugger.

Comment: Never heard of this limitation in VS2008 and I've debugged monster source code files before without trouble.  Line numbers are 64-bit values, compare to SymGetLineFromAddr64().  The non-64 version was removed a very long time ago.  Rebuild a static library if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to split the file in two, keeping each file under 65535 lines. There is rarely a good reason to have files that big. Optimizing was a weak reason in the past, but Visual Studio nowadays has `/LTCG` link time code generation for that.