# Debug very large file with VS Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS Studio 2015 to debug a very large file of 415797 lines written in C. The problem is that after the 84990th line, the debugger lost the track of the file, I just can't press F10 anymore. Lines before 84990 get the debug breakpoint ball filled with red (acessible). Lines after 84990, the ball is white filled ("The breakpoint will not currently be hit."). The binary file is about 100MB and the .pdb file is only 5MB. It's not generating the full .pdb file. What could be happening?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382809/visual-studio-2008-debugging-large-c-file) didn't help me.

Comment: Is this file filled mostly with data? Then you should extract it.

Comment: No, it's code. Data are in separated files.

Comment: Over 400,000 lines of code in a single file? Atrocious! Break it up into multiple files (many organizations have a coding standard that mandates a single method per file)  and recompile.

Comment: I would rewrite this from scratch, as nothing in this 400kloc file can be trusted to have the slightest quality.

Comment: It is a automatic generated code of a huge system. I don't have control over it. I just can't split the file. I just wanted to debug it.

Comment: Is it real code created by humans or is it the output from a decompiler of some sort? If it's machine generated, you should be able to have it generate smaller files.

Comment: It's generated by a not open source program.

Comment: How is it even compiled? I am surprised the compiler have not "lost tack" at some point.

Comment: Did you consider switching to Linux? I was able (painfully) to debug a 2MLOC generated C file on Linux (compiled with a recent `gcc` compiler and using a recent `gdb` debugger, on the command line). You may need 32Gbytes of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up the file into manageable parts would be the best course of action here.

A file of over 415K lines is much too large to be able to work with effectively, both from a tool point of view (as you've found out) and from a human point of view.  There's probably a lot of functions that aren't directly related to each other that don't need to be in the same file.  The question you linked mentioned keeping the size under 64K, so that means you're looking at making at least 8 separate source files, probably more.

Figure out which functions logically belong together and break out each set of related functions into their own source file, and create a header file for each with declarations of the ones that need to be accessed by other modules.  Then include those header files in the relevant source files so they can be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that a large generated C file can still be split in several pieces (with some work), as long as you don't have single huge functions (e.g. some single function with a hundred thousand lines). So I am expanding [dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52996177/841108) below.

Also, perhaps you could try using a Linux system (if your generated C file and program is easily portable to Linux). On Linux/x86-64, with a recent `gcc` compiler and a recent `gdb` debugger, I have been able to debug a 2MLOC generated C file (with many small functions, each less than a few thousand lines). You may need 32 gigabytes of RAM. Perhaps even [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) could be used on Windows (I guess it also could handle large C files).

To split a generated C file `foo.c` in several pieces (e.g. `foo1.c` and `foo2.c`), you might need a few days to do the following (since some human work is required):

first, indent the C code (perhaps removing `#line` directives before). You could use [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/). You get a C file where functions are clearly delimited (their body have a brace in column 1).

The copy&paste the `#include` lines of `foo.c` into both `foo1.c` and `foo2.c`. Copy cleverly (so take time to understand them) the global variables (probably verbatim into `foo1.c`, and with `extern` in `foo2.c`. For static variables, that need some work: you would rename them (perhaps with a unique enough prefix) to make them "global". So a `static int sv;` in `foo.c` becomes `int myfooprefix_sv;` in `foo1.c` ans `extern int myfooprefix_sv;` in `foo2.c`. Of course, you need a `#define sv myfooprefix_sv` (in both files) after that. A similar work is needed for static functions, so `static void dothat(int);` becomes `void myfooprefix_dothat(int);` followed by `#define dothat myfooprefix_dothat` etc.

At last, you copy&paste the functions definitions, so the first half of functions goes into `foo1.c` and the second half of functions into `foo2.c`

Try to compile the obtained program. Edit `foo1.c` and `foo2.c` to fix compilation and linking errors.

Such a manual (but tiring) splitting procedure usually works. Yes, that will take some time. There are pathological cases where that don't work (but usually generated C files don't fall in such cases).